# Modifying an already submitted slurm batch script

Tags: slurm

A job was submitted to slurm queue using a job script. Now, if i want to update the location of executable mentioned in one of the lines of the script, is it possible?

scontrol update job ..... is not having option to update the lines in the scripts

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The job scripts are located at the path configured as `StateSaveLocation` in the Slurm configuration but it might not be a good idea to modify it ; you might most probably break things. If you are not `root` on the cluster, you cannot do that anyways.

What you can do, is create a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) at the place where your script expects the executable, targeting the actual executable you want to run.